# Is there a way to calculate the difference of values between different columns and rows in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2, calculation

I want to calculate the difference of values in different columns and rows in DB2, like in the pic shows, I want to calculate the highlighted END_TS - START_TS. e.g END_TS: 8/19/2019 6:48:03 pm - START_TS: 8/19/2019 12:04:06 pm
[image]

I tried use this query, but it does not show the difference

```
SELECT 
t1.PROCESS_NM, 
t1.START_TS, 
t2.END_TS, 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(2,CHAR(t2.END_TS - t1.START_TS)) AS DURATION 
--4 is minutes, 2 for seconds, 8 for hours
FROM PROCESS_LOG t1, PROCESS_LOG t2
WHERE t1.PROCESS_NM=t2.PROCESS_NM
  AND t1.PROCESS_STATE ='BEGIN'
  AND t2.PROCESS_STATE = 'END'
  AND t1.WH_CREATE_TS> CURRENT TIMESTAMP -10 DAYS
  AND t1.PROCESS_NM LIKE ('%xxxxxxxxxxx%')
  AND t2.END_TS=
      (SELECT MIN(t3.END_TS) FROM PROCESS_LOG t3
      WHERE t1.START_TS <= t3.END_TS
      AND t3.PROCESS_STATE = 'END');
```

I expect to use the END_TS when "process_state" = "END" in right column to minus the START_TS when "process_state' = "BEGIN" in left

Answer (score 0):

If they are *always* interlaced, as in your example, you can use the `LEAD()` function to do it. For example:

```
select
  process_nm,
  start_ts,
  timestampdiff(2, char(next_end_ts - start_ts)) as duration
from (
  select
    *,
    lead(end_ts) over(order by wh_create_ts) as next_end_ts
  from process_log
) x
where process_state = 'BEGIN'
```

However, if they are not interlaced, this solution won't be helpful.